# MySQL NULL ошибка запроса SELECT

Tags: python, mysql

Всем привет, пишу парсер расписания.
Бывают ситуации когда нету у занятия учителя. Это например дисциплины - Физическая культура и иностранный язык. Потому что люди в разные секции ходят и разные группы посещают, поэтому в источнике для группы у таких занятий нету учителя.

База данных представляет собой 8 различных таблиц и 1 таблица, в которой указаны Id на записи в тех таблицах. Все со связью Один-ко-многим.

Имеется метод, который получает id преподавателя

```
def get_teacher_id(teacher):
    sql = "SELECT id from teacher where name = %s"
    data = (teacher,)
    rows = select_database(sql, data)
    print("Опа ", rows, teacher)
    if len(rows) == 1:
        return rows[0][0]
    else:
        sql = "INSERT INTO teacher(name) VALUES (%s)"
        return insert_database(sql, data)
```

Если количество возвращаемых записей равна 1, значит запись уже есть, поэтому мы вернем id, иначе добавим запись и вернем lastrowid.

Сейчас посмотрел полученную после парсинга таблиц, и получилось так, что имеется большое количество записей с NULL (а должно быть 1, это же как бы 1 преподаватель).

Сначала не понял почему так происходит, но потом выполнил запрос к таблице где куча NULL

```
SELECT
    `id`
FROM `teacher`
WHERE name = NULL;
```

И он вернул 0 записей, поэтому все добавляются все новые и новые записи, хотя могла быть 1.

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: @Mike спасибо, а что этот знак с точки зрения логики делает?

Comment: то же что и равно, только NULL равно NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любая операция с NULL, кроме `<=>` дает опять же NULL, так что NULL=NULL дает ложь (так же как и NULL!=NULL).

Если значение подставляемое в точку %s действительно NULL, то воспользуйтесь "NULL безопасным сравнением" (`<=>`) вместо `=`. А если это пустая строка то напишите для нее отдельное условие вида `name=%s OR (%s='' AND name is NULL)`

[Все операторы сравнения MySQL](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Comparison_Operators.html)